# How can I fix this circular predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Why doesn't this work to define "married" in Prolog?

```
married(X,Y):-married(Y,X).
```

Are these kinds of circular predicates not allowed?  How would I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Forgive me if I get the syntax wrong, it's been a while since I played with Prolog.

---

A typical solution is to introduce another level to the clauses, like this:

```
married(X, Y) :- wife(X, Y).
married(X, Y) :- wife(Y, X).
```

and then specifying the relations using the wife clause instead:

```
wife(jane, bob).
wife(alice, john).

?- married(jane, X).
X = bob
```

More information can be found here: [CSc 8710, Deductive Databases and Logic Programming, chapter 6 - Logic and databases](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/8710/sp07/ch6.pdf), under 6.5 - Special Relations.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the basic problem is that if circular definitions are allowed, although the resulting language is self-consistent, there can be subtle consequences which are often counter-intuitive. There are also efficiency considerations (circular definitions incur extra overhead).

See this [detailed discussion](http://www.cs.kuleuven.ac.be/~dtai/projects/ALP/newsletter/archive_93_96/net/impl/occur.html) for lots more explanation and quite a few different points of view.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use tabling, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679826/prolog-path-finding/740746#740746).